# transcribing stressed vowels in compound words in English

Tags: phonetic-symbols

If I am transcribing word such words such as "cupcake" and "homework," in IPA, should I always use a stressed vowel in both syllables, even though one syllable receives primary stress? For example, would I use schwar or right-hook reversed epsilon in the second syllable of the word "homework?"

Comment: There are a lot of different conventions for transcribing English; what do you do for a non-compound word that has multiple stressed syllables, like "Constantinople"?

Comment: If you are actually transcribing phonetics in IPA, you need to consult your supervisor or teacher. If you are transcribing English phonemics, on the other hand, you need to state which dialect of English you're transcribing, and which system of phonemic symbols you're using for the transcription. Many different English phonemic systems exist; they're similar but they differ in many ways, and you've mentioned several of them. Again, if you're being paid, consult your boss, and if you're doing it for your own satisfaction, take you choice among the variants.